# VHDL no function declaration for "=" (if statement, std_logic)

Tags: vhdl, function-declaration

I guess it's about time I got on here. So for school, I'm coding this VHDL control and I keep getting the same errors. I have searched through various similar questions, but couldn't quite find the sollution. Alas, I have to admit I'm an absolute beginner at VHDL, but the scientific assistents at school couldn't solve this, either.
Here's my code:

```
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 

use ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL; 



entity steuerung is 

  port  

  ( 

    Clk             : in std_logic;
    Reset           : in std_logic;
    AktPos          : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    Notaus          : in std_logic;
    Betrieb         : in std_logic;
    HPR             : in std_logic;
    HPL             : in std_logic;
    ESR             : in std_logic;
    ESL             : in std_logic;
    CntClr          : out std_logic;
    LedR            : out std_logic;
    LedG            : out std_logic;
    M_An            : out std_logic;
    M_Li            : out std_logic;
    M_Re            : out std_logic;
    State           : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
  );

end steuerung;


architecture behave of steuerung is
begin
        process(Clk, Reset, AktPos, Notaus, Betrieb, ESR, ESL)

            type statet is (auf, ab, steht, notaus, reset_ab, reset_auf);

            variable var_zustand: statet;

            variable var_ausgabe: std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);

        begin

            if Reset = '1' then

                var_zustand := steht;

            elsif(Clk'event and Betrieb = '1') then

                case var_zustand is

                    when steht =>

                        if (ESR = '0' and ESL = '0' and Notaus = '0') then

                            var_zustand := steht;

                        end if;

                        if (ESL = '1' and Notaus = '0' and ESR = '0') then

                            var_zustand := reset_ab;

                        end if;

                        if (ESR = '1' and Notaus = '0') then

                            var_zustand := reset_auf;

                        end if;

                        if (Notaus = '1') then

                            var_zustand := notaus;

                        end if;

                    when reset_ab =>

                        if (Notaus = '1') then

                            var_zustand := notaus;

                        elsif (ESL = '0' and Notaus = '0' and AktPos < "10111110100000000") then

                            var_zustand := ab;

                        elsif (Notaus = '0' and AktPos >= "10111110100000000") then

                            var_zustand := steht;

                        end if;

                    when ab =>

                        if (AktPos < "10111110100000000" and ESL = '0' and Notaus = '0') then

                            var_zustand := ab;

                        end if;

                        if ((ESL = '1' or AktPos >= "10111110100000000") and Notaus = '0') then

                            var_zustand := reset_ab;

                        end if;

                        if (Notaus = '1') then

                            var_zustand := notaus;

                        end if;

                    when auf =>

                        if (AktPos > "0100000110000000" and ESR = '0' and Notaus = '0') then

                            var_zustand := auf;

                        end if;

                        if ((AktPos <= "0100000110000000" or ESR = '1') and Notaus = '0') then

                            var_zustand := reset_auf;

                        end if;

                        if (Notaus = '1') then

                            var_zustand := notaus;

                        end if;

                    when reset_auf =>

                        if (Notaus = '1') then

                            var_zustand := notaus;

                        elsif (Notaus = '0' and ESR = '0' and AktPos  > "0100000110000000") then

                            var_zustand := auf;

                        elsif (AktPos <= "0100000110000000" and Notaus = '0') then

                            var_zustand := steht;

                        end if;

                    when notaus =>

                        if (Betrieb = '0') then

                            var_zustand := notaus;

                        end if;

                        if (Betrieb = '1') then

                            var_zustand := steht;

                        end if;

                    when others =>

                        var_zustand := steht;

                end case;

            end if;



                case var_zustand is

                    when steht =>

                        var_ausgabe := "000";

                        M_An <= '0';

                        M_Li <= '0';

                        M_Re <= '0';

                        LedR <= '0';

                    when ab =>

                        var_ausgabe := "010";

                        M_An <= '1';

                        M_Li <= '1';

                        M_Re <= '0';

                    when reset_ab =>

                        var_ausgabe := "001";

                        CntClr <= '1';

                    when auf =>

                    M_An <= '1';

                    M_Li <= '0';

                    M_Re <= '1';

                    var_ausgabe := "100";

                    when reset_auf =>

                        var_ausgabe := "011";

                        CntClr <= '1';

                    when notaus =>

                        var_ausgabe := "110";

                        M_An <= '0';

                        M_Li <= '0';

                        M_Re <= '0';

                        LedR <= '1';

                    when others =>

                        var_ausgabe := "111";

                        M_An <= '0';

                        M_Li <= '0';

                        M_Re <= '0';

                        LedR <= '1';

                end case;



                State <= var_ausgabe;

        end process;

end behave;
```

The errors I get are all

> ../hdl_temp/steuerung.vhd:40:95: no function declarations for operator
>   "="

but for several different lines (40, 43, 46, 49, 53, 55, 57, 61, 6467,
71, 74, 77, 81, 83, 85). I hope this is understandable despite some
German thrown in there.
I've been stressing about this for literally weeks, feeling like an idiot. What am I not seeing?

Comment: You used `notaus` at different places (once as a portname, once as an enumeration literal) which appears to confuse your toolchain. Remember VHDL is case insensitive.

Comment: Your error line numbers and column numbers don't match the pasted code.  The declaration of the enumeration literal nohause will hide the port nohause in the process. A process is an inner declarative region (IEEE Std 1076-2008  12.3 Visibility, 12.2 Scope of declarations, 12.1 Declarative region). "Basic identifiers differing only in the use of corresponding uppercase and lowercase letters are considered the same. "(15.4.2 Basic identifiers). (In the port and type statet declarations.) It's not a case of 'confuse your toolchain'.

Comment: @mfro It isn't confusing the toolchain. The toolchain follows the defined behavior of the language. The object (port) `Notaus` is hidden by the enumeration literal `notaus`. If you compile your code with e.g. [GHDL](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl), it would tell you this in a warning.

Comment: @Paebbels: I apologize for bad wording.

Of course it's not 'confused' in any way, but complaining about a missing overloaded equality operator to compare a std_logic to an enumeration literal.

Anyway, the root cause of the error is the shadowed port.